# The largest number of vectors which are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, orthogonality

$$v_1=(x_1,x_2,x_3\cdot\cdot\cdot,x_n)$$is such a vector. By changing its signs and positions of each component $x_i$, we can get different vectors. When n is odd, it's impossible for any of orthogonal to each other. When n is even, what is the maximum number of vectors that are orthogonal to each other.

For example, vectors $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$, $(-x_2,x_1,x_4,-x_3)$ and $(x_3,x_4,-x_1,-x_2)$ are mutually perpendicular when $n$=$4$.

What about $n=4,6,8,10,...$ and how many?

Comment: $(x_4,-x_3,-x_2,x_1)$ is mutually orthogonal to your 3 ?

Comment: Are you requiring these vectors to be orthogonal for arbitrary choices of the $x_i$?  There are specific vectors when $n = 3$ that make your statement about odd $n$ false;  for example, the vectors $(1,2,0)$ and $(-2,1,0)$ are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: we can't use concrete values for $x_i$

Comment: we can just use $x_i$ to represent that

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: $(x_4,-x_3,-x_2,x_1)\cdot (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=2x_1x_4 - 2x_2x_3$, which in general won't be zero. However $(x_4,-x_3,x_2,-x_1)$ seems to work.

Comment: I've changed a little bit

Comment: The fourth one was  $(-x_4, x_3, -x_2, x_1)$

Comment: so there 4 vectors orthogonal to each other in 4th dimension

Comment: Guess: The maximal number of mutually orthogonal vectors is the largest power of $2$ that divides $n$. Note that a set of one vector is trivially mutually orthogonal (it has no two different vectors, so it is vacuously true that any two different vectors are orthogonal).

Comment: what about 6, only two vectors mutually orthogonal?

Comment: @celtschk Thanks for the correction.

Comment: This is very close to the Hadamard matrix problem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix and the related maximal determinant problem, se https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_maximal_determinant_problem

Comment: Your vectors are equivalent to the matrix representation of Quaternions en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations, with the third column sign switched. Euler's four-square identity is identical to the second representation.[Degen's eight-square identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degen's_eight-square_identity) can be converted for 8 vectors - erase $a$ and each square is a vector. Becuase, of Hurwitz's theorem, I guess n is equal for the dimension only for n=1,2,4,8. Combining with @celtschk guess: the maximum amount of vectors is the largest power of 2 that divides n and 8.

Comment: Every such generic set of mutually orthogonal vectors gives rise to an invertible matrix subspace, so the number of such vectors is bounded above by the maximal dimension of nonsingular matrix subspace in $M_n(\mathbb R)$, which is known to be the Hurwitz-Radon number $\rho(n)$. For $n=1,2,4,8$, this upper bound is clearly sharp and the orthogonal vectors can be constructed from the multiplication tables of real/complex/quaternion/octonion numbers.

Comment: what about any even number, would you like to give a formal proof?

Comment: @i9Fn what do you mean the maximum amount of vectors is the largest power of 2 that divides n and 8

Comment: both n and 8 are divided?

Comment: Yes. Also, my guess can be constructed and serve as a lower bound, for $n=2^a m$ for $a \le 3$, just repeat the solution for $2^a$, $m$-times. If we believe the comment on https://oeis.org/A003484, then Hurwitz-Radon numbers, our upper bound, are equal for the lower bound if $n \not\equiv 0 \pmod{16}$. If $n \equiv 0 \pmod {16}$ i am not sure.

Comment: so 6 vectors only have 2 mutually orthogonal